unitarily related projection operators (group representation theory)
Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $D^{(\alpha )}$ be a unitary irreducible representation of $G$. Its dimension is denoted as $d_\alpha $.
We have the projection operator
$$ P_{ii } = \frac{d_\alpha }{|G|} \sum_{g\in G }    D_{ii}^{(\alpha ) *}(g) g. $$
I suspect that $P_{ii }$ and $P_{jj }$ are unitarily related. That is, we can find a unitary operator $U $ such that
$$ P_{ii } = U P_{jj } U^\dagger . $$
This is somehow obvious if we think of $P_{ii } $ as $e_{ii }$, the matrix whose only nonzero matrix element is 1 and is at $(i,i)$.
But how to prove it rigorously? $P_{ii} $ and $P_{jj }$ are elements of the group algebra. I guess $U $ can also be found in the group algebra.
